# Manhwa/webcomic about a noble lady reincarnated after dying from an unidentifiable disease

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga, reincarnation

From what I remember, the plot revolves a noble lady who was reincarnated after dying from an identifiable disease (resulting from magic?). The female lead married a noble man, due to loving him at first sight. Although the female lead's  father was against it, she married anyways. The female lead's husband turned out to be cheating on her (almost mocking her by bringing the mistress to their home) and stealing her wealth. She's recognized as the first woman to divorce her husband.

I don't remember her hair color, but it might have been brownish/auburn. She married the man before reincarnation and divorced him after reincarnation.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. What colour was the female lead's hair?

Comment: Did she marry the man and then divorce him before or after reincarnation?

Comment: Was the disease identifiable or unidentifiable?   The question and body are different.  From context, it seems that unidentifiable is what the body should be updated to.

Comment: @Xolia - If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. In order to do this though, you'll need to use the same account you used to post this question, or merge your new account with the previous one by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is ***[No More Turning a Blind Eye](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/no-more-turning-a-blind-eye)***.

From Anime-Planet:

> Ophelia Heavenwalker dies a pitiful death, succumbing to a mysterious illness at the exact moment she witnesses her husband’s infidelity. So when fate gives her a chance to redo the last three years of her life, she decides she’s done being a doormat. She’s taking back her name, taking back her estate, and taking back her life! Now’s the time for Ophelia to enjoy her independence and budding romance, but will that be possible with her failing health and spiteful ex-husband still in the picture?

The protagonist, Ophelia Heavenwalker, was the sole heir of a wealthy count. When she met Stein at age 19, she fell in love with him at first sight, and, before long, they were married, against her father's wishes.

However, Stein only married her for her money, and had a mistress, who moved in them with under the pretense of being his student. At age 25, Ophelia died from an unknown disease, which she speculated might've been a curse from Stein. The last thing she saw before dying was Stein and his mistress making love.

Then she awoke in the body of her 22-year-old self, and recalling the last three years of her previous life, resolved not to repeat her mistakes, and to pay Stein and his mistress back for their cruelty. Soon after, she met with an attorney to initiate divorce proceedings.

[image] [image]